# Minimum Oracle Java VM heap memory setting?

Tags: java, jvm

Is there a minimum -Xmx setting for Oracle's JVM? It looks like -Xmx2M does provide the application with more than 2 MB of heap size, as the Java Memory MX bean tells me it allocates like 10 MB...

Is there a minimum under which the JVM silently ignores the Xmx setting?

Comment: When the heap is small, it is a very small portion of the size of the JVM.  I am not sure why this matters at that point.

Comment: I'm developing a framework with lazy loading (and unloading) in low-memory conditions, I want to test what the minimum Xmx settings are for my framework.

Comment: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/gc-tuning-6-140523.html

Comment: I know about this page but cannot find any documented minimum Xmx setting.

Comment: I would assume that a real application would do more than your framework does.  If you can run with the minimum heap you can set I am not sure what the concern is.

Comment: However, I don't know the minimum heap size...obviously 2M seems too small as this does not limit the VM heap size to 2MB (or the memory MX beans are lying)

Comment: I would try Runtime.totalMemory(), see below.

Answer (score 2):

If I run

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Heap size is " + Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory() / 100000 / 10.0 + " MB");
}
```

with `-mx8m` on Java 7 update 25 64-bit I get

```
Heap size is 8.0 MB
```

but if I run with `-mx2m` I get

```
Heap size is 3.2 MB
```

So it does appear you get slightly more heap than you asked for for very small sizes.  However, even for a small mobile device I wouldn't be worrying about every last MB because the JVM itself is much larger (can be over 100 MB of shared memory, thread etc)

i.e. if you can't spare a few MB, you won't be able to run the JVM anyway.

Comment: It is a little bit weird: minimum heap size seems to be 2M, otherwise the JVM won't start at all. However, if 2M is specified we get 3.2M instead. Is there n definitive answer to the question: Why is that so?

Comment: I can only guess it adds some to s you JVM can start, but I don't know for sure.  Perhaps reading the source of OpenJDK would have a comment as to why this is done.

Answer (score 0):

For jvm to start minimum 2mb of heapsize is required. You can set heap size to 0 bytes, but jvm will not start.
And maximum heap size recommended is 1/4 of total ram.